# awk: print the first 11 columns (leaving out the last column)

Tags: csv, awk

My CSV file has 12 columns (tab-delimited), and I want to print out the first 11 columns. I came up with this following awk code, but it ruins the format (no tab delimiter any more). I need some help to maintain the format while only printing out the first 11 columns. Help is appreciated.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<12;i++)printf "%s",$i OFS}'
```

Comment: Have you tried to `cut` it?

Comment: what about `awk '{for(i=1;i<12;i++)printf "%s\t",$i OFS}'`?

Comment: Yeah. cut might be a little more suitable for this purpose. That being said you need to set OFS to your desired delimiter (namely tab).

Comment: @Rubens: yes, I tried "cut", and it works. I just want to sharpen my awk skill a little bit :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do what you want assuming you want a single tab between each input field.

```
awk -vOFS='\t' '{NF=NF-1}1' $file
```

`-vOFS='\t'` set `OFS` to a tab character.

`NF=NF-1` tell awk that the line has one fewer field than it started with and cause it to recompute the value of `$0`.

`1` patterns have a default of print so use any true value to print `$0`.

Try `awk '{NF=NF-1}1' OFS='\t' $file` instead or failing that `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {NF=NF-1}1' $file` to avoid `-v`.

Comment: awk: invalid -v option

Comment: @TonyGW, does your system have: `gawk`, `nawk`, or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`?

Comment: +1, but you must specify OFS before the filename.  If you do `awk {...} file1 OFS='\t' file2`, then OFS will only be set to a tab for file2.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Right, sorry, transcription error on my part (and my fault for not noticing the difference). Fixed.

Comment: You could use `NF-=1` to subtract `1`

Answer (score 1):

Some `awk` variaton

```
awk 'NF-=1' OFS=\\t $file
awk '{NF-=1}1' OFS=\\t $file
awk '{NF-=1}1' OFS="\t" $file
awk -v OFS="\t" '{NF-=1}1' $file
```

Comment: That first one will fail (awk error for negative NF, at least with gawk 3.1.5) on blank lines and will entirely drop lines with only a single field (as opposed to printing a blank line as might be desired).

Answer (score 0):

if you have Ruby on your system

```
# ruby -ne 'puts $_.split("\t")[0..10].join("\t")' file
```